# Organize Data from DB in 6-hour Intervals SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to fetch data from my database in 6-hour intervals. Database information: SQL Server 2000. My working code to get hourly data is as follows:

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DateData), 0),
AVG(OtherData) AS AvgData
FROM DATASITE
GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DateData), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DateData), 0);
```

How would I create a query to get data in 6-hour intervals, rather than hourly intervals?

Comment: You get the hour part out then divide it by 6 to put it into a 6 hour bucket: `DATEPART(hour,DateData)/6`. Replace all of your `DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DateData), 0)` with this and see if it's what you're after

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEPART` and integer rounding to get 6-hour buckets, like this:

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(hour,DateData)/6 Bucket,
AVG(OtherData) AS AvgData
FROM DATASITE
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour,DateData)/6
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour,DateData)/6;
```

Keep in mind that the buckets will correspond to midnight-6AM, 6A-12P, 12P-6P, and 6P-midnight, and that they will be denoted 0, 1, 2, and 3 by the query above.

Comment: So this will average all of the days into four periods, returning 0, 1, 2, and 3 datetimes for all of the data. How would I go about getting the 6-hour data per day? For example, say that the data spanned a week and I wanted to get the 6-hour data for each day in that week separately?

Comment: @aioko Add a `cast(DateData AS date)` into your `select`, `group by`, and `order by` to split the intervals out by each day as well.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson The Datedata is stored as DateTime in the database already, the cast doesn't seem to be affecting anything.